# VMWare Workstation Connect VM to internet through SOCKS5

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, socks5

How can I connect a VM in VMWare Workstation to the internet through a proxy of type SOCKS5 ? The host OS is Windows, while the guest OS is linux/ubuntu.

P.S. I need it to be configured OUTSIDE guest; i.e. from Windows so that all connections made by ALL apps inside vm are passed through proxy